# c# autorefresh values displayed from a class

Tags: c#, list, object, ping

I have a `host_object` class (custom defined) which has `x` parameters, among which you find a PingReply: ping rtt value

however since many pings range from 10ms - 300ms they have different `refresh` times, thus querying the `getPing()` method will have a differnet value for each ip address

Is it possible to query each of the host objects displaying (to i.e. the console) the `object.getPing()` value as the new value is determined?

Comment: Hi, can you please post the code? Especially the class and method.

Comment: You can capture the ping return as an event.  See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.pingcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day all

For what it is worth, I resorted to another method, I used threading to check each ping time and display them to the console.

I was not able to do it asynchronously with the main loop code